# select box dropdown showing black background in ubuntu OS(Mozilla Firefox Browser)

Tags: javascript, php, css, node.js, vue.js

I'm using MDB Bootstrap 4 in vue.js. I have used a select box in my web page its working fine in all browsers and OS but in Ubuntu OS(Mozilla Firefox Browser) the select box drop down is showing back background while hovering it's showing orange background. I don't know how to fix this issue can anyone help me out. I have attached the screenshot and my coding

```
<select class="mdb-select">
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Here is the sample image for this issue
[image]

Comment: Are you using any themes in firefox? This is most likely client side.

Comment: It's not issue. This is rendered by the OS and the HTML. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select/7208814)

Comment: @ pj100 no i'm not using any theames in firefox